# How to tell if vectors are parallel?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given the vectors GH = 5/6(2p+q) and vector JK = 5/18(2p+q), how do we know these two vectors are parallel?

I suspect it has something to do with (2p+q) that determines the two vectors are parallel but I can't seem to understand why. In addition why is the magnitude of GH considered to be larger than JK?

Comment: I can not understand the problem: how are defined the components fo the vectors? From your question it seems like GH and JK are fractions (i.e. numbers)

Comment: I believe they are vectors expressed in term of p and q

Comment: Sorry still not clear: are p and q real numbers? In that case I can not see how GH and JK are vectors

Comment: Two vectors are parallel.  That means: one of them is a scalar multiple of the other.  So, we have to prove that $\frac56(2p+q)$ is a scalar multiple of $\frac{5}{18}(2p+q)$.

Comment: P and q are also vectors, and I believe vectors GH and JK are expressed in terms of these vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since vectors as directed line segments are invariant to parallel translations, two vectors are parallel if and only if one of them is a scalar multiple of the other one.

Here both given vectors are scalar multiple of the vector $2p+q$, so they are both parallel to $2p+q$ and hence to each other.

Comment: Thank You. Does vector GH also have a larger magnitude because 5/6 > 5/18?

Comment: Yes, we actually have $\vec{GH}=3\cdot\vec{JK}$.